# plot of multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have imported and processed multiple datasets in numpy/python- from the datasets I can created several arrays with the data - 
for the sake of argument let's say 3 arrays;
A
B
C
now I want to plot the data:

currently I chose each array, 
and plot the data - this is fine, but when I have 18 arrays, then it becomes at least non efficient

so I tried, to create a list and iterate through each array:

```
allarrays = [A, B, C] #where A, B and C are arrays
for array in allarrays:
    pylab.figure()
    .......
    .......
    .......
    pylab.show()
```

with that A plots fine, but B comes empty, and then it stops

I imaging that doing a list of arrays is probably not the proper way, but cannot seem to figure it out
any ideas welcome

Dimitris

the actual code as requested - the arrays (A12, A23 etc have been created in a previous step)

```
enter code here

allarrays = [A12, A23]#, A34, A45, B12, B23, B34, B45, C12, C23, C34, C45,]
size = len(A12)
for array in allarrays:
    to_plot=np.zeros(shape=(size, 5))
    plt.figure() # so each figure is a fresh start
    for i in range(0, size, n):
        to_plot=np.array(array, dtype='float')
        plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
        plt.xlim(0.1, 1000)
        plt.xlabel('frequency')
        plt.ylabel('phase(mrad)')
        plt.semilogx(to_plot[i:i + n, 0], to_plot[i:i + n, 2], 'o-', color=next(colors))
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.hold(True)
        plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
        plt.xlim(0.1, 1000)
        plt.xlabel('frequency')
        plt.ylabel('imag(S/m)')
        plt.loglog(to_plot[i:i + n, 0], to_plot[i:i + n, 3], 'o-', color=next(colors1))
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.hold(True)
     plt.tight_layout()
     plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code, I assume that is where the problem is?

Comment: Consider using subplots instead, and/or using `savefig()` to dump the plot to a file.  This may help you partition the problem into issues which are local to just some interactive backends.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, and as #debianplebian suggested the problem was with the followup code - 
I actually needed to define colors within the high level loop - I failed to do so and when the 2nd iteration reached the color it stuck